# Android Studio different picture size on different devices

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

i'm writing android code for about 2 months.
Now there is the first point i'm stucked with.

I thought using dp for sizes results objects different on different resolutions.

In the concrete project i have an imageview with the dimensions:

```
width: wrap_content
height: 250dp
```

On my Galaxy S4 the complete layout looks fine, but on my Galaxy S2 the `ImageView` has the same size and the layout don't fit the screen.

- Did i misunderstood the use of dp?
- How is it possible to scale an object right depending on the
  resolution of the screen?

Thanks in Advance

Marcus

Edit: I have only 1 version of my image in the drawable folder.

My layout is written like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/curtain2">

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/ValuesImageView"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/overview_values2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ValuesTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/Text_Values"
    android:id="@+id/ValuesTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/Text_Indipendence"
    android:id="@+id/IndipendenceTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ValuesImageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="@string/Text_Choose"
    android:id="@+id/ChooseTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/IndipendenceTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/Text_Start"
    android:id="@+id/StartTextView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ChooseTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Text_Button_Start"
    android:id="@+id/StartButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    style="@style/btnStyleBlackpearl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/StartTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The drawable file for the background is resized correctly.

Do i have to add an image for every resolution (mdpi, hdpi...)?

Is there a tool to convert an image to the different resolutions?

I want the Values `ImageView` resize at smaller displays too, but the height seems to be fixed at 250dp if i compare the display of both phones.

Sorry for the lated answer, id didn't expect answers that quick.

+1 for this :)

Comment: Do you have different sizes of the image in the various mdpi, hdpi, etc. folders?

Comment: "I thought using dp for sizes results objects different on different resolutions" -- `dp` handles different screen densities. "On my Galaxy S4 the complete layout looks fine, but on my Galaxy S2 the Imageview has the same size and the layout don't fit the screen" -- without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we have no good way of advising you on your specific problem.

Comment: No, your not completely wrong, there is a difference, because you can't always divide the amount of pixels into even parts - there are no "half pixels" and this can result in annoying differences (the result won't be "pixel-perfect"). I'm not sure if you are facing this issue or if you missed something else.

Answer (score 0):

You should create resource directories as follows : layout-large and layout-xlarge. Then in those directories, you should put the same xml files (with the same names) that in the layout directory. And in the xml in the large and xlarge directories, you can adapt the size of image and all others elements to larger screens (for example put the same image but with a bigger resolution).

From android developers : *The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge.* (if you don't create small, the default layout directory will be used for all screen sizes smaller than large).

I think small is until 4 inches screens, normal until 6, large until 8 or 9 and xlarge is for the largest sizes.
You can test it with all types of phones with the previews in the IDE.

320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).

480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).

600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).

720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

You can compare then with indications I gave above.

Comment: is layout large the same as layout-sw600dp?

Comment: Ok, now i've tried it with the small, normal, large,xlarge version and with the sw-600dp,sw-720dp version, but it doesn't matter. In all situations the layout on the s2 istn't the rxpected one. :(

Comment: The galaxy s2 has a for size 4.3 inches I guess. So it probably used the normal or small layout. You have to exactly name the directory layout-small, layout-normal, etc. And in each directory, the xml files have to have the SAME name. In those xml, put the same content, just change the size of the images and other things as you want. You can verify first with the preview in the IDE, and with your real phone after. Note that the emulators have bugs with these layouts and just use the normal, but if you have  a real phone there is no problem

Comment: Do i have to change the image itself in these layouts or just the dimensions of the image?@Jey10

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but i think this is a general question which i have to be clear with and hopefully i ask this question only one time, but no matter what i try it looks like the s2 and the s4 use the same layout all the time. Maybe someone hat a step by step way to define an image /layout for different screensizes and resolutions?

Comment: I gave you a total step by step procedure. It should works, but it's normal that the s2 and s4 use the same layout because they have a screen size of 4.3 and 5". And as I said : small is until 4 inches screens, normal until 6. They use both the normal, the size is too close

Comment: Put the exactly same contents, just changing the dp of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jey10 who pushs me into the right direction.

The following solves the problem to me:

I added the following layout-folders:

```
layout-hdpi
layout-mdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-xxhdpi
layout-xxxdpi
```

With layout-small, layout-normal... there was a problem, because both phones are declared as layout-nromal devices with different desitys.

So give the layoutfolders the desityreference let android choose the right layout.

Thanks for the help and sorry for the poor first post, i promise to improve myself.